# How to grep lines from a log file that have the current date?

Tags: date, logging, grep

I need to grep a log file with today's date, but the output is showing for more than today's date.

```
grep date +"20%y-%m-%d" /path/log/General.log | grep "EmpID#106496" /path/log/Genral.log
```

Output:

```
2013-06-19 14:47:05,996 - INFO  EmpID#106496 
2013-06-19 14:47:05,996 - INFO  EmpID#106496 
2013-06-21 00:01:24,915 - INFO  EmpID#106496 
2013-06-21 00:01:24,915 - INFO EmpID#106496
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use the `date` output as a pattern in `grep`:

```
$ grep "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")" file
2013-06-21 00:01:24,915 - INFO   
2013-06-21 00:01:24,915 - INFO
```

That is, you need to enclose the `date` sentence to make it be processed. Also, note I used `Y` instead of your `20%y`.

---

> I am looking for a sepcific `EmpID` in the logs with current date.

Then pipe to another grep:

```
$ grep $(date +"%Y-%m-%d") file | grep "EmpID#106496"
2013-06-21 00:01:24,915 - INFO  EmpID#106496 
2013-06-21 00:01:24,915 - INFO EmpID#106496
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to add space delimited fields in date command use double quotes around $() :

```
$ grep "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")" file
2013-06-21 00:01:24,915 - INFO   
2013-06-21 00:01:24,915 - INFO
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually executing 'date', because it's not been surrounded by backticks. The command should be

```sh
grep `date +"20%y-%m-%d"` /path/log/General.log
#    ^--                ^--
```

Right now, as written, you are searching for the word `date` in two different files (`+"20%Y-%m-%d"`, and `general.log`).