# Matching a date in a file on Unix

Tags: unix, sed, grep, find

I have the following `unix` command, which I'm using to try finding a date in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` in a file:

```
grep -i -w [\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}? <filename>
```

but for some reason I'm getting an empty answer. Am I matching the regex correctly for grep?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep a log file with current date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17238908/608639)

Answer (score 1):

The following is working, using bash extended regex (`-E`, `--extended-regexp`):

```
grep -E -i -w "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" <filename>
```

But, in this case you should use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

If you want to use `\d`, you need to specify the PERL regex (`-P`, `--perl-regexp`):

```
grep -P -i -w "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}" <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below grep commands,

```
grep -oP '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}' file
```

OR

```
$ grep -oE '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' file
```

OR

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}' file
```