# How to select from the output of grep?

Tags: linux, grep

I want only to extract the date from the name of this file:

So I did this:

```
echo HNR.L04.C07.ldd.T2018050.BG.nc.nc |grep -o '[0-9]\+'
```

I got this:

```
 04
 07
 2018050
```

Now I want to select the third line? any idea?

Comment: Last one or the third one? Add `| tail -n 1` to get the last one, see [demo](https://ideone.com/Qrc5h7).

Comment: That did it. thanks alot

Comment: You are grepping for numeric strings, not dates. Possible duplicate of [Grep a log file with current date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17238908/608639), [Matching a date in a file on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26416963/608639), etc. More generally, [how to grep for date in a file site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+grep+for+date+in+a+file+site:stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the firthd line of output with:

```
set -n 3p
```

You can get the last line of output with:

```
tail -n 1
```

Ex:

```
echo HNR.L04.C07.ldd.T2018050.BG.nc.nc | grep -o '[0-9]\+' | sed -n 3p
```